# SSIS script task can't read project variable

Tags: ssis, script-task

In my project.params I have variables such as `LampUserName` of type string.  In my 
 script task I'm then trying to read them like so:

```cs
        foreach (var name in new string[] { "ServerName", "InitialCatalog", "UserName", "Password" }) {
            if (!Dts.Variables.Contains(string.Format("$Project::Lamp{0}", name))) {
                writer.WriteLine(name);
            }
        }
        string server_name = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::LampServerName"].Value;
        string database = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::LampInitialCatalog"].Value;
        string username = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::LampUserName"].Value;
        string password = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::LampPassword"].Value;
```

Every one of those prints out that it doesn't exist and then an exception is thrown.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referencing your project parameters from a Script Component within a Data Flow Task?  If so, this differs from using a Script Task within the Control Flow.  After adding the project parameter in the ReadOnlyVaraiables field, it is accessible as a property of the Variable object.

```
string database = Variables.DatabaseParameter.ToString();
```